# calling curl from java windows works but not linux

Tags: java, linux, curl

this is driving me crazy, i did this code that works 100% in java, but not in linux tried escaping in all ways.

here is the cdoe:-

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args = new String[] {"curl", "-v", "http://www.solarmovie.is/forum/login/",
     "-c", "\"cookies2.txt\"",
     "-b", "\"cookies2.txt\"",
     "-H", "\"Host: www.solarmovie.is\"",
     "-H", "\"Origin: http://www.solarmovie.is\"",
     "-H", "\"User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36\"",
     "-H", "\"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\"",
     "-H", "\"Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\"",
     "--compressed", "",
     "-H", "\"X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\"",
     "-H", "\"Connection: keep-alive\"",
     "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-\"",
     "-H", "\"Referer: http://www.solarmovie.is/\"",
     "--data", "\"referer=http\"%\"3A\"%\"2F\"%\"2Fwww.solarmovie.is\"%\"2F&login\"%\"5Blogin\"%\"5D="+username+"&login\"%\"5Bpassword\"%\"5D="+password + "\""
});
```

on windows it:-

```
{"status":false,"data":{},"messages":["Wrong username or password."]}
```

on linux prints

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0   135      0   3639 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3639
106  2733    0  2733    0   135  14649    723 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17436

curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

with alot of data in top (the page loading with 404 error)

so what i think in linux java is trying to request more than 1 request ? its doing wrong split or something.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "works 100% in java, but not in linux". On which OS did it work? Can you post a simple java class with the code that works on whatever OS where it worked?

Comment: on windows it worked fine, centos 404 errors and malformed url

Comment: Can you post the unescaped string[] concatenation you actually provide to the pbuilder, by using a debugger or, better, a for String s: [] System.out.print(s+" ") ?

Comment: for(String arg: args){System.out.print(arg +" ");}

already did that, and i tried running the command from the output directly on the centos it worked fine... but from java always fails.